# C# Making a game in picture box

Tags: c#, xna, sdl, picturebox

I am making a 2D game in C# using picture box, but to me it seems the performance is kinda bad. Though it might be just because of my bad optimization.

I heard about SDL and XNA and was wondering if I should use any of them and which one?

The game is intended solely for windows and I am planning on implementing multiplayer later so some library to help me with networking would be cool too.

The game I am making is 2D game similar to Phage Wars if you know it.

Comment: Have you looked into Unity? It has UnityScript which is somewhat similar to Javascript as a scripting language.

Comment: Unity also supports scripting in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use XNA, it also has all the power of .Net to handle networking

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend XNA. I got into it a few months ago and i find it both easy (for a 2D game even easier) to understand and powerful. On the downside Microsoft stopped working on XNA :(
Anyways, if you want to take a closer look at XNA I recommend this tutorial: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/xna-tutorials
I haven't worked with Unity yet, but if you think you will still be making games in a few years then it might be worth to take a look at it (as it is not dead like XNA).

Answer (score -1):

Monogame, http://www.monogame.net/

Uses the XNA code interface (so if u roll back to vanilla XNA you will not loose everything), in developpement (version 2.3 as far as i know), also compatible with mobile, linux, mac. It seems to me what it uses SDL when compile for windows.

Unity is great too, but too big and too powerfull from me point of view, just wanted to make some 2D game efficiently.

Also take a look to SharpDx, which is a .net wrapper for directx. More complex use, but can be a good way to start learning directx.

Answer (score -1):

Consider Unity3D as an option.
You can create 2d and 3d games, there is large community, the Windows version is free (i mean, compiling for Windows) and your code can be written in c# or Javascript (or Boo... but it's not that common).
I know it's an old post, but it might be good for someone else with the same question.

Answer (score -1):

**1. PictureBoxCanvas class**

Create a new class called PictureBoxCanvas and paste in the following code to it:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class PictureBoxCanvas
{
    public uint[] Pixels { get; set; }

    Bitmap Bitmap { get; set; }

    GCHandle Handle { get; set; }

    IntPtr Addr { get; set; }

    bool IsRefreshing { get; set; }

    PictureBox PctCanvas { get; set; }

    public PictureBoxCanvas(PictureBox pctCanvas)
    {
        PctCanvas = pctCanvas;

        Reset();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        // Initialise resources

        Size ImageSize = new Size(320, 240); // This sets the resolution to 320 pixels wide and 240 pixels high. Modify this to any dimension you wish

        PixelFormat fmt = PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb;

        int PixelSize = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(fmt);

        int Step = ImageSize.Width * PixelSize;

        int padding = 32 - (Step % 32);

        if (padding < 32)
        {
            Step += padding;
        }

        Pixels = new uint[(Step / 32) * ImageSize.Height + 1];

        Handle = GCHandle.Alloc(Pixels, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        Addr = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(Pixels, 0);

        Bitmap = new Bitmap(ImageSize.Width, ImageSize.Height, Step / 8, fmt, Addr);

        PctCanvas.Image = Bitmap;
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        // Update

        if (!IsRefreshing) // If computer is too slow then this will hold the next frame until the current one has finished
        {
            try
            {
                IsRefreshing = true;

                PctCanvas.Refresh();

            }
            catch //(Exception ex)
            {
                //Console.Out.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm") + ":" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace); // Uncomment to display exception info if desired
            }
            finally
            {
                IsRefreshing = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Finished so free up resources

        PctCanvas = null;

        Addr = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (Handle.IsAllocated)
        {
            Handle.Free();
        }

        Bitmap.Dispose();

        Bitmap = null;

        Pixels = null;
    }

}
```

**2. Add controls and events**

Create a new form in your project and add the following controls/events to it:

- PictureBox named, "PctCanvas"
- Timer named, "Tmr25Hz". Set the interval to 40 i.e. 1000 ticks per second / 25Hz. Also double-click the control to create an event method for it
- Add "Closing" and "Load" event methods via the events (lightning) icon in the Form properties

Note: These will be empty. Add missing code from the next section.

**3. Example Form code**

If creating a new project from scratch then your code behind should look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PictureBoxOfVersatility
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PictureBoxCanvas PictureBoxCanvas { get; set; }

        Random Random { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This code runs after the Form has finished initialising

            Random = new Random();

            PictureBoxCanvas = new PictureBoxCanvas(PctCanvas);

            Tmr25Hz.Start();
        }

        private void Tmr25Hz_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Modify the Pixels array i.e. move on to the next animation frame

            for (int i = 0; i < PictureBoxCanvas.Pixels.Length; i++)
            {
                // These three lines are responsible for choosing a randomly coloured pixel

                byte Red = (byte)Random.Next(0, 255);
                byte Green = (byte)Random.Next(0, 255);
                byte Blue = (byte)Random.Next(0, 255);

                PictureBoxCanvas.Pixels[i] = ((uint)(Red | (Green << 8) | (Blue << 16) | 0xff000000));
            }

            // Refresh the PictureBoxCanvas

            PictureBoxCanvas.Refresh();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            // This method runs when the Form is closing

            Tmr25Hz.Stop();

            PictureBoxCanvas.Dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

**4. Compile, Run and Modify**

This project should now compile and run by pressing the F5 key.

The first time you run it you will see white-noise. This is not a mistake, but this is because each pixel is being given a random colour every frame.

It is now up to you to replace the random code i.e. in the Tmr25Hz_Tick method with your own.

The way this is done is by modifying the values in the pixel array. Each pixel has an red, green and blue value between 0 and 255.

You will need to correograph the animation yourself, but this is entirely up to you to arrange.

If you don't know where to begin then I would start by pasting different shapes and images over the pixel array.

Once you have mastered this then think about how you might sequence events together, possibly by having a list of wait times and instructions.

**5. Where to go from here?**

The versatility of PictureBoxCanvas is immense. Advanced users will eventually be able to utilise graphics hardware to help render their scenes using DirectX or OpenGl, however this is beyond the scope of this tiny introduction.

I hope this is enough information to get started and having fun, but please ask if you have any comments, questions or suggestions.